# C# How to dispose of OpenFileDialog file

Tags: c#, wpf, dispose, openfiledialog, writeablebitmapex

I use `OpenFileDialog` to get the path of an image and then set it to my image source property `imgSelected.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filenameSteg, UriKind.Absolute));` in a WPF application.

The thing is, I need to open that file again later but I can't open it since the file is *being used by another process* ( `System.IO.IOException` -> `The process cannot access the file` *pathToFile* `because it is being used by another process.`).

The code that needs to access it later it as follow :

```
 bitmapSource = JpegBitmapDecoder.Create(File.Open(filenameSteg, FileMode.Open),
                BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames[0];
```

This `bitmapSource` is used to give that image to a `WriteableBitmap` and from there I go through the pixels.

Is there any way to dispose of a *File* opened with an OpenFileDialog ?

I tried to cast to to IDisposable, to use a using block and so on but this thing is persistent.

**EDIT :**

1 - I tried this (@ctacke answer) :

```
 using (var stream = File.Open(filenameSteg, FileMode.Open)){
        bitmapSource = JpegBitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None,
        BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames[0];}
```

But it still gives me the error about the process being already in used by another process because even though it will be disposed after, I still am trying to open the same file (`filenameSteg`) than I opened in the `OpenFileDialog`. (Or at least, that's how I see it.)

2 - I then tried this (based on @ctacke recommended [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542217/load-a-bitmapsource-and-save-using-the-same-name-in-wpf-ioexception):

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filenameSteg+1, FileMode.Create)){
       MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
       BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
       byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filenameSteg);
       memoryStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
       memoryStream.Position = 0;

       bi.BeginInit();
       bi.StreamSource = memoryStream;
       bi.EndInit();

       bitmapSource = bi;}
```

**Note :** Notice that I here ask for `filenameSteg +1`. That is because I wanted to test the rest of my method so I create a copy the file and simply added a 1 to its name. That being said, when using `filenameSteg` for real, it gave me the same error about being already in used which I again suspect is that I still am asking to open the same image that was previously opened in the `OpenFileDialog`.

3 - I thought of another approach which does not require me to dispose the opened image :

When I open the image for the first time in the `OpenFileDialog`, I store the byte array of the image in a variable so I could create the `WriteableBitmap` using the `BitmapFactory` and the byte array.

```
// This is in the OpenFileDialog. It is where I stock the image "pixels" in a byte array.
bytesArrayImage = File.ReadAllBytes(filenameSteg); 
//And then later when I needed the WriteableBitmap, I used the byte array and the BitmapFactory
//imgSelected being the Image containing the image I opened in the OpenFileDialog, I used it's
//width and height 
wb = BitmapFactory.New(Convert.ToInt32(imgSelected.Width),
     Convert.ToInt32(imgSelected.Height)).FromByteArray(bytesArrayImage);
```

The problem with this approach is that, some pictures works fine and I can use the byte array to create the `WriteableBitmap` and go through it's pixels but in other cases it gives me an `AccessViolationException` stating : `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`. In other words, trying to bypass the dispose problem got me into another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should release the original image, something like this:

```
if(imgSelected.Source != null)
{
    imgSelected.Source.Dispose;
}
imgSelected.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filenameSteg, UriKind.Absolute));
```

Next, `File.Open` returns a stream, which you need to explicitly release.

```
using(var stream = File.Open(filenameSteg, FileMode.Open))
{
    var bitmapSource = JpegBitmapDecoder.Create(stream,
        BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames[0];
}
```

See also: [Load a BitmapSource and save using the same name in WPF -> IOException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542217/load-a-bitmapsource-and-save-using-the-same-name-in-wpf-ioexception)

Comment: Thanks @ctacke for the fast reply, I edited my question with both the method you referred me to ( using a using block to get the stream and then it would be disposed ) and the one in the link you gave as information. I also put the current state where I am now after I tried to bypass it.